# Is it possible to scroll multiple lines of auto-completion with Control-p and Control-n in vim?

Tags: vim

The Vim [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-P) states that one can use `Control-p` to go to the previous match. However, if I want to go up 10 lines in the autocompletion menu, I need to type Control-p ten times.

Is it possible to specify a count so I can scroll up (or down) 10 rows without the extra keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

This will do pretty much what you ask for:

```
function! CleverTab(cnt)
    return repeat("\<C-P>", a:cnt)
endfunction

inoremap 2<C-P> <C-R>=CleverTab(2)<CR>
inoremap 3<C-P> <C-R>=CleverTab(3)<CR>
inoremap 4<C-P> <C-R>=CleverTab(4)<CR>
"....
```

Answer (score 0):

All printable characters are inserted "as-is" so `10<whatever>` is impossible out of the box. You can use `<PageUp>` and `<PageDown>` but they behave exactly how you would expect so, if the goal is to select a match somewhere in the middle of the visible menu, they won't help.

One hacky solution could be to map *n* non-printable keys that do `<Down>` *n*  times but that doesn't sound practical at all.

Or you could intercept numbers and do `<Down>`/`<Up>` for as many times as specified but handling multiple digits seems like a hassle and how would you handle actually inserting digits?